# Footer not appearing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a footer for a website, but the footer just wont appear no matter what I do, I have checked everything I know thta imght be causing the issue to happen, but it's still the same. I just want the footer to appear, just a simple footer at the end of the page, sorry if the code is not properly embeded, im not familiar with this platform yet

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  object-fit: contain;
  z-index: -1;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------Header Content-------------------------------------------------*/

.header_neon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2%;
  background-color: rgb(216, 36, 223);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.header_cont {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(104, 15, 107)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)75%);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.header_icon img {
  width: 70px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px 50px 0 50px;
}

.header_title {
  color: #fcee0a;
  font-family: 'Cyberpunk';
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu_container {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

.menu_list {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid #fcee0a;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_item {
  width: 25%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Blender';
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

.menu_sub_list {
  margin-left: -65px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid #fcee0a;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu_sub_list a {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu_item:hover .menu_sub_list {
  display: block;
}

.menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #fcee0a;
  color: black;
}

.menu_sub_list a:hover {
  background-color: #fcee0a;
  color: black;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cyberpunk';
  src: url("font/Cyberpunk.otf") format('opentype'), url("font/Cyberpunk.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Blender';
  src: url("../font/Blender-Pro-Book.otf") format('opentype');
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------Bdoy Content-------------------------------------------------------*/

.body_cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.media_container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fcee0a;
}

.body_txt_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #fcee0a;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 100px 10% 0 10%;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.body_cont h2 {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  color: #fcee0a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Blender';
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.body_cont h4 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  font-family: 'Blender';
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.body_txt_container img {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.deco_sides1::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  background: #fcee0a;
  display: block;
}

.deco_sides2::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  background: #fcee0a;
  display: block;
}

.more {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Blender';
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.enroll_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.enroll_container img {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.enrollment_form {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.deco_form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  background-color: #fcee0a;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
}

.etiqueta {
  background-color: #fcee0a;
  font-family: 'Blender';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.campo_txt {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #fff98b;
}

.register {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: 'Cyberpunk';
  width: 30%;
  height: 15%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.terms a {
  font-family: 'Blender';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.register:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------Footer--------------------------------------------------------*/

.foot_cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.foot_txt_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #fcee0a;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 100px 10% 0 10%;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-content ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer-content ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.footer-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="background">
      <img src="images/background.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="header_cont">
      <div class="header_neon"></div>
      <a href="index_final.html">
        <div class="header_icon"><img src="images/samurai.png"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="header_title">Humanisick</div>
      <div class="menu_container">
        <ul class="menu_list">
          <li class="menu_item">
            Juegos
            <ul class="menu_sub_list">
              <a href="#">Catalogo</a>
              <a href="#">Carrito</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu_item">
            Personajes
            <ul class="menu_sub_list">
              <a href="#">El asesino</a>
              <a href="#">La encantadora</a>
              <a href="#">El luchador</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu_item">
            Chatbot
          </li>
          <li class="menu_item">
            Idioma
            <ul class="menu_sub_list">
              <a href="#">Inglés</a>
              <a href="#">Español</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body_cont">
      <div class="media_container">
        <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source src="video/ghostrunner.mp4">
                </video>
        <audio autoplay loop>
                    <source src="audio/Air.mp3">
                </audio>
      </div>

      <div class="body_txt_container">
        <h2>La era de la inhumanidad ha llegado</h2>
        <h4>Ahora que has sentido el llamado hacia la inhumanidad, te rendirás al mundo digital. Deja todas tus preocupaciones afuera y únete a nosotros. Este es el momento exacto para entregarte al mundo digital y olvidar lo que alguna vez fuiste. Lo único
          que importa de ahora en adelante es quién vas a ser en este mundo. </p> ¿Cómo resolverás tus problemas de ahora en adelante? </p> La vida no será más fácil por ya no ser humano, y eres tú quien decidirá cuál es la mejor manera de vivir tu nueva
          vida de aquí en adelante.</h4>
        <img src="images/samurai.png">
      </div>

      <div class="enroll_container">
        <div class="deco_sides1"></div>
        <img src="images/girl.png">
        <div class="mas_info">
          <div class="more">
            Humanisick es una compañia ficticia que se dedica a la venta de videojuegos bajo la promesa de hacer que sus usuarios se pierdan en el mundo digital olvidando todos sus problemas de la vida real, dandoles un momento de relajacion en donde pueden vivir
            emocionantes historias de ficcion y fantasia.<br> Si quieres conocer más al respecto, dejanos tu informacion y con gusto daremos contigo.
          </div>
          <div class="enrollment_form">
            <form action="procesar_registro.php" method="post">
              <label class="etiqueta" for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
              <input class="campo_txt" type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br>

              <label class="etiqueta" for="correo">Correo Electrónico:</label>
              <input class="campo_txt" type="email" id="correo" name="correo" required><br>

              <label class="etiqueta" for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>
              <input class="campo_txt" type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" required><br>

              <button class="register" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
            </form>
            <div class="terms">
              <a href="#">Terminos y condiciones</a>
            </div>
            <div class="deco_form"></div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="deco_sides2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="footer-content">
        <p>&copy; 2023 Mi Sitio Web</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acerca de</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to check the tags in html, the classes in css but nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you validated your HTML at all? You have a `</p>` nested inside a `<h4>`. Looks like there could be more errors besides.

Comment: I have, i mean, I want the footer to appear after the email form

Comment: Footer appears for you, but not where you think. It’s basically not clear to me why you are limiting the height of the `.main` and `.body_cont blocks`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `height: 100vh;` from the `.body_cont` class.

```css
.body_cont {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100vh; */
}
```

Comment: @SebastianBarragan - Then you should accept the answer!